# AS3: Clicking a button via actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This is my very simple code:

```
g2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttG2);
function buttG2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    buttonNote="G2";
    addWholeNote();
}
```

It works great when I click the button, but is it possible to fire this function from another function using Actionscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some other function:

```
function otherFunction() {
    buttG2(null);
}
```

You pass in `null` since it is never used. You could also give the parameter a default value like this:

```
function buttG2(event:MouseEvent = null):void
{
    buttonNote="G2";
    addWholeNote();
}
```

And then call the function without any parameters as event will then be `null` as per default:

```
function otherFunction() {
    buttG2();
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys! I got the same answer from both of you, picking the one that was first, upvoted both :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a default parameter of null to allow the function call from elsewhere in your code. You won't be able to get any mouseevent data, but that's probably not an issue. You could pass null into your function as you have it, but I find this to be cleaner.

```
g2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttG2);
function buttG2(event:MouseEvent = null):void
{
    buttonNote="G2";
    addWholeNote();
}
```

call it like any other function, the param is now optional.

```
buttG2();
```